# PHP Function To Get Character Number

Tags: php, iteration

How can I write a function that gives me number of the character that is passed to it

For example, if the funciton name is `GetCharacterNumber` and I pass `B` to it then it should give me `2`

```
GetCharacterNumber("A") // should print 1
GetCharacterNumber("C") // should print 3
GetCharacterNumber("Z") // should print 26
GetCharacterNumber("AA") // should print 27
GetCharacterNumber("AA") // should print 27
GetCharacterNumber("AC") // should print 29
```

Is it even possible to achieve this ?

Comment: Is this a custom order? Do you have a table with all the possible values?

Comment: Do you want it to return values for "AAA", "AAHJSNDJS" etc?

Comment: What should `BA` return?

Comment: no, I am not using tables... I am actually referring to character iteration like A, B, C,...AA, AB, AC

Comment: Are you using this for some sort of spreadsheet? If so, what library are you using?

Comment: @MarkBaker you guessed it right.. am using it to write spreadsheets

Comment: If you're using PHPExcel to write those spreadsheets, look at the columnIndexFromString() method in the PHPExcel_Cell class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very efficient but gets the job done:

```
function get_character_number($end) 
{
    $count = 1;
    $char = 'A';
    $end = strtoupper($end);
    while ($char !== $end) {
        $count++;
        $char++;
    }
    return $count;
}

echo get_character_number('AA'); // 27
```

[demo](http://codepad.org/vtUzjjYF)

This works because when you got something like `$char = 'A'` and do `$char++`, it will change to 'B', then 'C', 'D', … 'Z', 'AA', 'AB' and so on.

Note that this will become the slower the longer `$end` is. I would not recommend this for anything beyond 'ZZZZ' (475254 iterations) or if you need many lookups like that.

An better performing alternative would be

```
function get_character_number($string) {
    $number = 0;
    $string = strtoupper($string);
    $dictionary = array_combine(range('A', 'Z'), range(1, 26));
    for ($pos = 0; isset($string[$pos]); $pos++) {
        $number += $dictionary[$string[$pos]] + $pos * 26 - $pos;
    }
    return $number;
}

echo get_character_number(''), PHP_EOL; // 0
echo get_character_number('Z'), PHP_EOL; // 26
echo get_character_number('AA'), PHP_EOL; // 27
```

[demo](http://codepad.org/UPxdlNpU)

Comment: @Sachyn The version with [ord](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14358603/956397) is faster and cleaner.

Comment: For a more optimal solution check my answer, for example it worked for 'ZZASDAASDAA', the result was generated in 0.0001 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your advice, i have checked @Dutow's answer too, which is also brilliant and will use it depending on my requirement

Answer (score 11):

There is a function called [ord](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) which gives you the ASCII number of the character.

```
ord($chr) - ord('A') + 1
```

gives you the correct result for one character. For longer strings, you can use a loop.

```
<?php
    function GetCharacterNumber($str) {
        $num = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
            $num = 26 * $num + ord($str[$i]) - 64;
        }
        return $num;
    }
    GetCharacterNumber("A"); //1
    GetCharacterNumber("C"); //3
    GetCharacterNumber("Z"); //26
    GetCharacterNumber("AA"); //27
    GetCharacterNumber("AC"); //29
    GetCharacterNumber("BA"); //53
?>
```

Comment: for AA, it genrates (((0*26)+1)*26)+1, which is the correct answer. For BA, it is (((0*26)+2)*26)+1, which is also correct, I think. So double letters are correct. For "AAA", it calculates 26*27+1, which should also be correct (26 for single letter variations, 26*26 for double letters, and this is the first three letter code)

Answer (score 3):

Use range and strpos:

```
$letter = 'z';
$alphabet = range('a', 'z');
$position = strpos($alphabet, $letter);
```

For double letters (eg zz) you'd probably need to create your own alphabet using a custom function:

```
$alphabet = range('a', 'z');
$dictionary = range('a','z');
foreach($alphabet AS $a1){
    foreach($alphabet AS $a2) {
        $dictionary[] = $a1 . $a2;
    }
}
```

Then use $dictionary in place of $alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code that does what you want.

Tested it and works perfectly for the examples you gave.

```
define('BASE', 26);

function singleOrd($chr) {
    if (strlen($chr) == 1) {
        return (ord($chr)-64);
    } else{
        return 0;
    }
}


function multiOrd($string) {
    if (strlen($string) == 0) {
        return 0;
    } elseif (strlen($string) == 1) {
        return singleOrd($string);
    } else{
        $sum = 0;
        for($i = strlen($string) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            $sum += singleOrd($string[$i]) * pow(BASE, $i);
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ord should be a more efficient way to have your number :

```
$string = strtolower($string);
$result = 0;
$length = strlen($string);
foreach($string as $key=>$value){
   $result = ($length -$key - 1)*(ord($value)-ord(a)+1);
}
```

and result would contain what you want.